How to access groovy global variable from another file
I have a groovy script aa.groovy:
a = 'foo'

and a second script bb.groovy:
import aa
println "$a"

But it doesn't work. I've tried every combination of
def a = 'foo'
a = 'foo'
@Field a = 'foo'

and ...
println "$a"
println "$aa.a"

I can think of, but I  can't get it to work.

You need @Field, but then you also need an instance from the class. Or you have to declare the field static.
cat <<\EOT > 'aa.groovy'
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field a = 'dynamic'
@Field static b = 'static'

EOT
cat <<\EOT > 'bb.groovy'
import aa
println(new aa().a)
println(aa.b)

EOT

other option in addition to cfrick's answer

aa.groovy
class aa {
  static b = 'static'
}

bb.groovy
import aa
println "$aa.b"

